# Asynchronously loaded Images all show in the UI at the same time

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, asynchronous

**MediaImage Class** (Model)

```
public class MediaImage : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MediaImage(FileSystemInfo file)
    {
        this.Uri = new Uri(file.FullName);
        this.Label = file.Name;

        var getThumbnail = this.LoadThumbnail(this.Uri);

        getThumbnail.ContinueWith(task =>
        {
            this.Thumbnail = task.Result;
        });
    }

    public Uri Uri { get; }

    public string Label { get; private set; }

    private BitmapImage thumbnail;

    public BitmapImage Thumbnail
    {
        get { return this.thumbnail; }
        private set
        {
            this.thumbnail = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    private async Task<BitmapImage> LoadThumbnail(Uri uri)
    {
        return await Task.Run(() => this.GenerateThumbnail(uri));
    }

    private BitmapImage GenerateThumbnail(Uri uri)
    {
        var sourceBitmap = new BitmapImage();

        sourceBitmap.BeginInit();
        sourceBitmap.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
        sourceBitmap.DecodePixelWidth = 100;
        sourceBitmap.UriSource = uri;
        sourceBitmap.EndInit();
        sourceBitmap.Freeze();

        return sourceBitmap;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

**MainWindow C#**

```
public partial class MainWindow
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void OnLoadImagesClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var dialog = new FolderBrowserDialog();
        if (dialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            this.MediaImageView.LoadImages(dialog.SelectedPath);
        }
    }
}
```

**ImageView XAML** (Interface)

```
<Grid>
    <ListBox Style="{DynamicResource ImageViewListBoxStyle}"
             ItemsSource="{Binding Images}"
             ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource ImageViewListBoxItemStyle}">
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Panel.ZIndex="1000" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Label}" Foreground="White" Width="100" Height="20" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                        <TextBlock.Background>
                            <SolidColorBrush Opacity="0.50" Color="Black"/>
                        </TextBlock.Background>
                    </TextBlock>
                    <Image Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Source="{Binding Thumbnail, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="100" Height="100"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

**ImageView C#** (Interface code)

```
public partial class ImageView
{
    public ImageView()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.Images = new ObservableCollection<MediaImage>();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    public ObservableCollection<MediaImage> Images { get; }

    public void LoadImages(string path)
    {
        this.Images.Clear();

        var option = SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly;

        var files = new DirectoryInfo(path).EnumerateFiles("*", option);

        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            // Skip images already in our image collection
            if (this.Images.Any(x => x.Uri.AbsolutePath == file.FullName))
            {
                continue;
            }

            this.Images.Add(new MediaImage(file));
        }
    }
}
```

**Gif of problem behaviour**

[image]

**Notes**

Through researching and learning it was my understanding that by setting `UpdateSourceTrigger` to `PropertyChanged` in my XAML, each Image should update it's binding when the asynchronous task completes and the `Thumbnail` property triggers a `PropertyChanged` event.

Each image in the `ListBox` should update it's source when the asynchronous task completes (Regardless of the other images and tasks) but that doesn't seem to be happening. In my current build it seem all the images update when the last task has completed.

**Question**

Is there an easy way to modify my code so that my model (MediaImage) updates certain properties asynchronously and the ListBox updates each item as it's task is completed (Preferably via a `PropertyChanged` event)?

Comment: `UpdateSourceTrigger` has no effect on a OneWay Binding. It controls when a TwoWay or OneWayToSource updates the Source property of the Binding. And setting it to `PropertyChanged` has nothing to do with the `PropertyChanged` event of the INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

Comment: Try to add random delay to `GenerateThumbnail` (via `Thread.Sleep`) so that each thumbnail generation takes different time and see what happens.

Comment: You may want to take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43124089/1136211) for an example of how to load and show images asynchronously.

Comment: Thanks for the link Clemens! The linked answer is exactly what i want to achieve. I'll study up and post my answer when i solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

My solution in a nutshell:

First, you have to set it's visibility to false.
Than you have to wait for all images to be loaded.
You can use FrameworkElement.Loaded event (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.loaded(v=vs.110).aspx).
Finally, if every Image has been loaded successfully, set their visibility to true.

Comment: Hey Nagi, thanks for your answer. I'm not looking to hide the image while it's loading, rather i want the interface to load the image asynchronously and show the image when it's loaded.