# How to load BMP image files into ImageSource of Image control with less memory usage and with good performance

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, bitmapimage, imagesource

We want to load BMP images in our application. 
Please suggest how to load BMP image files into ImageSource of Image control with less memory usage and with good performance ?

We used below codes, we are able to load the images but it takes huge time to load with more memory usage (even with the usage of DecodePixelHeight/Width )

```
var image = new BitmapImage();
image.BeginInit();
image.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
image.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreImageCache;
image.UriSource = new Uri(FullName);     //FullName is image name with path
image.DecodePixelHeight = 150;
image.EndInit();
image.Freeze();
ImageSource = image;
```

We need to load a folder of size 1GB of bmp files (each of size 5-10 MB). As of now initial load takes 6 minutes. But others images like JPG and PNG files of 1 GB data loads below 30 seconds

Comment: Apparently you've done everything you could do to minimize memory consumption. How many of these images are you going to load? One thing left to try: load the BitmapImage directly from a FileStream instead of an Uri.

Comment: Note also that only the PNG and JPEG decoders natively support DecodePixelWidth/Height. The others decode at original size and scale the bitmap afterwards.

Comment: WPF isn't really good in loading huge numbers of large images. Please define what is "good performance" for you. Does it need to load fast or to show fast? What image sizes are we talking about?

Comment: Take a look at [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43122740/how-to-load-and-show-images-asynchronously/43124089#43124089) for how to load images asynchronously.